# Remove parent li after click child image

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to remove the parent `li` when I click on the child image using angular. Here's what I have so far:

**View**

```
<ul class="cg-tag-list">
    <li ng-repeat="tag in list">
        <span>{{tag}}</span>
        <img src="" ng-click="fnRemoveTag()"/>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
//Remove Tag
$scope.fnRemoveTag = function () {
   // Put Code here
}
```

Comment: why jquery tag for?? are you looking for solution in jquery as well??

Comment: @MilindAnantwar: no only in angular

Answer (score 4, accepted):

pass the `tag` to the `fnRemoveTag` function;

```
<ul class="cg-tag-list" >
  <li ng-repeat="tag in list">
      <span>{{tag}}</span>
      <img src="" ng-click="fnRemoveTag(tag)"/>
   </li>
</ul> 

$scope.fnRemoveTag = function (tag) {
    // get the index of the tag which we are going to remove
    var index = $scope.list.indexOf(tag);

    // remove that tag from the `list` array
    $scope.list.splice(index, 1);

    //this will automatically update the dom for you
}
```

here is a [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/Jiddr8ZvJVz8K3gyyerK?p=preview)

---

and note that you can pass the `$index` of the instead of `tag` like

```
<img src="" ng-click="fnRemoveTag($index)"/>
```

and remove the element in controller as,

```
$scope.fnRemoveTag = function(index) {
    // remove that tag from the `list` array
    $scope.list.splice(index, 1);

    //this will automatically update the dom for you
}
```

example [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/PP33sv55nj2MMKjoxvdl?p=preview)

if you don't use the `orderBy` in the `ng-repeat` then use the `$index` other vise use the `tag`, because if you use `orderBy` it will sort the array according to sort description and when you pass the `$index` it may not the correct index of `$scope.list`.

for EX:

say you have array like `$scope.list = [3, 2, 1];` and you need to ng-repeat this with order by

```
<li ng-repeat="tag in list | orderBy:tag">
```

after the `orderBy`, `ng-repeat` will repeat the sorted array, but actually `$scope.list` remain as before & it will not gonna sort only the repeat order gets change.

so `$index` is the `ng-repeat`'s index and its not represent the index of `$scope.list`, if you do not use the `orderBy` then both will be same.

then when you try to remove from the `$scope.list` with the passed `$index` it will may not remove the correct element.

see this [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/Zsjl1NZ0u1hpJX3ZGsoo?p=preview)

try to remove first one and note that it actually remove the last one. because we pass the `$index` as `0` to the function and remove the `0`th index element of the `$scope.list` which has value of 3.

hope that makes sense.

Comment: glad to help you here :) cheerz

Answer (score 1):

View

```
<ul class="cg-tag-list" >
      <li ng-repeat="tag in list">
          <span>{{tag}}</span>
          <img src="" ng-click="fnRemoveTag(tag)"/>
       </li>
    </ul>
```

JS

```
//Remove Tag
$scope.fnRemoveTag = function (listItem) {
   var index = $scope.list.indexOf(listItem);
   if (index > -1) {
     $scope.list.splice(index, 1);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have jQuery you can use this:

```
var li = $(this).closest("li");
li.parent().remove(li);
```

Comment: Need answer in angular only

Answer (score 0):

Simply put $index as function parameter then use array splice method.

**View**

```
<ul class="cg-tag-list" >
  <li ng-repeat="tag in list">
      <span>{{tag}}</span>
      <img src="" ng-click="fnRemoveTag($index)"/>
   </li>
</ul>
```

*Javascript* (**don't use orderBy filter in this purpose**)

```
$scope.fnRemoveTag = function (index) {
    $scope.list.splice(index, 1);
 }
```